# Accessing bean from JSP and servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to figure out how to access a Java bean from a JSP and a servlet.

I've previously been fine with using beans just from JSP with useProperty. I would like to interact with those same beans through my servlet and it is not working.

I have this in my servlet. This is called after submitting a form.

```
public class Login extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String user = request.getParameter("user");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

    UserBean userBean = (UserBean) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
    if (userBean == null) {
        //this prints
        out.println("userBean is null");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("user", new UserBean());
        userBean = (UserBean) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
        if (userBean == null) {
            //this DOES NOT print!
            out.println("userBean is null");
        }
    }

}
}
```

This always comes up as null. I can create a UserBean myself and insert it and it's fine for the one page load, but I refresh and it's null again. I want it to last for the duration of the client's session.

Equally, I can do this in a JSP for example test.jsp:

```
    <jsp:useBean id="user" scope="session" class="my.code.UserBean" />
    <jsp:getProperty name="user" property="accesses"></jsp:getProperty>
    <jsp:setProperty name="user" property="accesses" value="cat"></jsp:setProperty>
```

And that works, it will display my default accesses value ("dog") from the bean, I know useBean will create a bean if there are none found. If I reload my test.jsp, I think it should print "cat" instead of "dog" now since we just created a bean and adjusted the accesses value, but it still prints "dog". If I again check if the servlet knows of a user bean, it will turn up as null.

From what I've read, I'm doing it right & this should work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where are you setting the `user` variable when you try and get it from the session?

Comment: I don't think I'm inserting it into the session myself, though I figured the useBean in the JSP would insert it for me. I updated the post for the full code for the servlet where I do try to insert a new UserBean.

Comment: yeah you're getting null because you're not setting the value anywhere. What you should be doing is hitting the servlet url, then creating your user object and then sending it to the jsp for view. (instead of trying to view it directly in the jsp without making any http requests)